# Overwrite listener without handler reference, is it ok to access the (possibly private) events property on a Ext.data.store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm working on replacing an [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) load event handler.

The variable me is different every time within the code block but me.store is the same (obtained via StoreManager.lookup). I want the store event listener to update the various me references. Best way i could find was to add another listener (and delete the old one since i don't need it anymore)

I haven't been able to use un / removeListener i.e. it had not effect.

I've found that i could replace the it by accesing the `me.store.events` and popping the listener from the load event. However this feels hacky and it might make the code dependant on a specific ExtJS version (4.2) since i don't know if it's a private property or not.

Also me.store.hasListeners['load'] doesn't get notified so it only helps because it removes the actual listener but not in the intended manner. The docs don't mention it, but i'm wondering if it may be an inherited property which can be accessed freely.

Are there any alterntives to the working approach i've come to? Can i remove all event handlers for an event without having a reference to the handler? Or is there a simpler approach i'm missing?

```
    var me =  this; // an enriched Ext.form.FormPanel,  different every time code runs
    me.store //obtained via StoreManger.lookup - so the same every time
    me.storeLoaded = function (store, records,successful, opts) {
        // some code to select a record from records and use it  
        me.loadRecord(record);
        } 
    };

    if (!me.store.hasListener('load')) {
        me.store.on('load', me.storeLoaded);
    } else{
        //tried this, but it doesn't remove it, probably because me.storeLoaded is different each time (parentForm is different)
        me.store.un('load', me.storeLoaded);

        //this feels hacky, i couldn't find out if events is a private property
        if (me.store.events && me.store.events['load']){
            me.store.events['load'].listeners.pop()
        }
        me.store.on('load', me.storeLoaded);
    }
```

Comment: I can't see what you are trying to do, but a `store` has already an `isLoaded` property. After it's loaded it will sync records..

Comment: The variable me is different every time, whereas me.store via a StoreManager.lookup. I want the store event listener to update the various me references. Best way i could find was to add another listener (and delete the old one since i don't need it anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement adding/removing listeners is using the `destroyable` parameter as described in the [addListener](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-removeListener) function. That way, you can always be sure which one is removed.

Example:

```
setActive:function(cmp) {
    cmp.myActiveListeners = cmp.eventStore.on({
        destroyable: true,
        load:cmp.refreshStores,
        filterchange:cmp.refreshStores,
        scope:cmp
    });
},
setInactive:function(cmp) {
    Ext.destroy(cmp.myActiveListeners);
},
```

I cannot recommend to blindly remove ALL listeners, since they may be added by other components (e.g. combobox) that you add later. To track down these bugs will grow you quite some gray hairs.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good use of destroyable +1 for that. However the problem is me is changed every time the code runs but store remains the same (obtained via a storemanager lookup). So when i look at me.store.hasListeners  and i see a listener, i can't remove it your way because myActiveListeners will not be defined on the component (in my case cmp=me).

Comment: I can remove all listeners because the store is used for one component alone and only it. However i was able to find a clearListeners method.

Comment: Well, you could do it using `store.myComponentListeners = store.on({`... so that, should you EVER try to add other listeners, or should they be added by Sencha, you won't be doomed.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i was thinking about. Trying to choose between this approach, which i prefer more or the clearListeners approach. I think i fancy yours

Comment: I will use this approach. I was reluctant to polute the store with a property, since i don't know if it's a good practice to do that.

Comment: My concern is best framed in this article on maintaining JavaScript: don't modify objects you don't know.
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer in [this article ExtJS overwrite listener:](http://programminglist.blogspot.ro/2013/09/extjs-overwrite-listener.html)

> Sometimes you need to overwrite an event listener in ExtJS.  Usually
>   listeners are registered like this `myStore.on('load',
>   this.myFunction, this);` then to remove our previously registered
>   listener, all we have to do is call un (which is an alias for
>   removeListener):  `myStore.un('load', this.myFunction, this);`
>
> But, what happens when you don't know what function is registered?
>   Sometimes you will not have a reference to the original function that
>   was registered. This situation may arise if there is code that exists
>   in a different flow or may even come as a package! If that is true,
>   the you may not be able to get a reference to the javascript function
>   or edit the existing code. In this case, we will have to look at all
>   of the functions that are registered for this event. We can then
>   remove the listeners just for a certain event by calling
>   **clearListeners**.

`clearListeners` was the method i was looking for.

It would seem he uses the `events` property so i assume it is a valid  use. It could be translated in my case to:

```
me.store.events.load.clearListeners()
```

However since i will only be using the load event on this particular store, i will simply call on them all.

```
me.store.clearListeners()
```

Thanks to Alexander, by suggesting not to remove all listeners that actually helped me find the article. However i will stil go with his solution, even if it polutes the store object because i like it better than clearing all listeners on a store, even if only for a specific event.